# Starting off on the wrong foot

Tags: discussion, questions

If your question gets off to a bad start, how do you fix it?

Today I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893750/formatting-floating-point-to-a-specific-number-of-significant-digits) that I thought was relatively straight-forward. However since I included working code in the question and wasn't explicit about what I was asking for, a couple of people assumed it was off-topic and should be moved to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and threw in a downvote for good measure.

Personally I still think it's on-topic and would be useful knowledge to have on the site. But at this point I can't know if the downvotes have simply made it invisible or if the comments have turned it into poison, or if there simply isn't an answer. It certainly isn't seeing any action.

I've considered just deleting the question and re-asking but that doesn't seem like the right thing to do. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: _'I've considered just deleting the question and re-asking but that doesn't seem like the right thing to do. '_ I wouldn't bother, along some clarifying points in the re-asked question.

Comment: Not sure what you thought you could accomplish by moving the code into an answer.  I've found a duplicate of your question though: http://stackoverflow.com/q/374316.  FWIW, Stack Overflow doesn't make a very good search service.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for finding the duplicate, but it's not really a duplicate - that one is for rounding the `double` value while mine is for converting to a string. Subtle difference, but crucial. I did attempt to search before posting the question, but came up dry.

Comment: Converting to... a string?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I moved the code because I wanted to make it clear that I wasn't looking for commentary on the code itself. I simply wanted to know if there was a more idiomatic way of doing it.

Comment: Converting to a string is a trivial operation, once you have a `double` with the correct resolution.  Getting the right number is simply a matter of rounding in a way that takes into account the number of significant digits you want.

Comment: @RobertHarvey not just converting to a string, but converting to a string with the proper number of digits and without scientific notation.

Comment: You won't get scientific notation if you use the right mask in your `ToString()` call.

Comment: The flaw I see here is that you forgot the basics: SO is a "question and answer" site, and what you posted does not contain a question. You can't have an *answer* without there first being a *question* asked. If you'd posted your "question" in the form of one, and then posted a self-answer, it probably would have been fine. You made it a "Here's a blog post that I'm going to break into two halves", and that isn't the proper format here.

Comment: @KenWhite there *was* a question there, but in hindsight I can see that I did a really poor job of explaining it. If I can paraphrase here, the question was "what's the built in or idiomatic way to accomplish this task?" Usually people are exhorted to share their code, but I think the question would have been better understood if I had left the code out entirely.

Comment: You cant put the answer in the question.  "works but seems overly complicated" is a statement not a question. "leaves me wondering if there's something built in which I have missed" is vague, questions don't need fluff.  "what's the built in or idiomatic way to accomplish this task" sounds like a recommendation question. At 133k rep you should know this :)  Just leave the question and move on, I doubt you will be question banned for it.

Comment: @JK. The "works but..." was added after I edited the code out of the question. I added it because I didn't want anybody thinking I held it to be the definitive answer. I've already admitted that my poor phrasing had a lot to do with the response. And a "recommendation question"? I don't quite understand that. If I was asking for an external library I could see it, but I was asking about the built-in capabilities of the language and bundled library.

Answer (score 1):

If I was to critique your question/answer, I would say:

- your question isn't a question, it is a statement
- your answer is a block of code with no real explanation of how it solves the "question"
- and in addition to that you state it's "overly complicated" which is kind of open and ambiguous - are you looking for help to fine tune it, or are you being self deprecating?

<strike>FWIW I don't think Robert's (original) dupe is correct, I think I understand what you are doing.</strike> You either need merge the question/answer into one (in which case it would be better on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)), or you need to make it into a more formalised question/answer.

When using the question-self-answer feature, remember that the question and answer must be able to stand by themselves. So make sure the question is a proper question, and consider writing the answer as if you were answering someone else - it may help with the way you phrase it.

Comment: What about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/158172/102937) then?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yep, I think that's the one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey if that's the best anybody can come up with in 5 years, I guess there really is no idiomatic way to do it. And thanks for the tips slugster, I'll look at rewording things further based on your suggestions.

Comment: Or maybe I'll just copy my answer to that thread and close my question altogether.

Comment: The question is already closed.